# How shall I understand and use this server written in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver

I am trying to understand a simple server written in   node.js

```
var http = require('http'); 
var querystring = require('querystring'); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
  switch(req.url) { 
    case '/form': 
        if (req.method == 'POST') { 
         console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url); 
         var fullBody = ''; 
         req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
           fullBody += chunk.toString(); 
         }); 
         req.on('end', function() { 
           res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});   
           res.write('<html><head><title>Post data</title></head><body>'); 
           res.write('<style>th, td {text-align:left; padding:5px; color:black}\n'); 
           res.write('th {background-color:grey; color:white; min-width:10em}\n'); 
           res.write('td {background-color:lightgrey}\n'); 
           res.write('caption {font-weight:bold}</style>'); 
           res.write('<table border="1"><caption>Form Data</caption>'); 
           res.write('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>'); 
           var dBody = querystring.parse(fullBody); 
           for (var prop in dBody) { 
            res.write("<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>" + dBody[prop] + "</td></tr>"); 
           } 
           res.write('</table></body></html>'); 
           res.end(); 
         }); 
       } else { 
         console.log("[405] " + req.method + " to " + req.url); 
         res.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
         res.end('<html><head><title>405 - Method not supported</title></head><body>' + 
                 '<h1>Method not supported.</h1></body></html>'); 
       } 
      break; 
    default: 
      res.writeHead(404, "Not found", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
      res.end('<html><head><title>404 - Not found</title></head><body>' + 
              '<h1>Not found.</h1></body></html>'); 
      console.log("[404] " + req.method + " to " + req.url); 
  }; 
}).listen(8080);
```

What does  the function `req.on()` do? For example, `req.on('data',...)` and `req.on('end',...)`? Is this explained somewhere in https://nodejs.org/api/http.html? I think I might have missed it.

How shall I send a HTTP request to the server so that the part inside `case '/form': if (req.method == 'POST'){...}` is executed? Specifically, when using `curl`, what arguments and options shall I give to `curl`? What if using Firefox browser?

Comment: `Is this explained somewhere` they are events https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

Req.on('data') means your server is receiving the data from the client, in callback attached to req.on('data') you generally concatenate the data and then parse the data to be used later. Once it has received the entire data then the callback attached to req.on('end') will be executed and here you can do all the business logic based on the data you received and then send the response back to the client

**now how can you access the /form URL?**

When sending data via a POST or PUT request, two common formats (specified via the Content-Type header) are:

1. application/json
2. application/x-www-form-urlencoded

you can either use postman client or curl to access the /form URL.

in curl-

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "param1=value1&param2=value2" \
http://localhost:8080/form

curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' \
http://localhost:8080/form
```

In your code you are accepting the application/x-www-form-urlencoded so go with the first one

Comment: Thanks. (1) How would you use curl to sent a HTTP POST request required to execute the part of the code? (2) Is postman a utility which can run on Linux or an extension to web browser?

Comment: Thanks.  Is postman a utility which can run on Linux or an extension to web browser?

Comment: on windows, postman can be installed as standalone software or as a browser extension. on Linux i have not tried, but this link may be useful http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/09/install-postman-app-easily-via-snap-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: -d flag implies a POST request